# How to set up DDMenu with Storyboards with XCode 4.2?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, storyboard

I tried out the DDMenu from https://github.com/devindoty/DDMenuController.

Has anybody an idea/tutorial how to implement the DDMenuController class with the storyboard functionality of XCode 4.2?

The problem I face at the moment is to connect the left and right controller with outlets to another view controller.

Best regards, hijolan